# AttributeError: 'Audio' object has no attribute 'speech'

Tags: openai-api

```py
from pathlib import Path
import openai

speech_file_path = Path(__file__).parent / "speech.mp3"
response = openai.audio.speech.create(
    model="tts-1",
    voice="alloy",
    input="The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."
)
response.stream_to_file(speech_file_path)
```

line 6, in 
response = openai.audio.speech.create(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\openai_utils_proxy.py", line 22, in **getattr**
return getattr(self.**get_proxied**(), attr)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Audio' object has no attribute 'speech'